# Отладка ошибок современного js на стороне клиента

Tags: javascript, отладка

Все знают как отлаживать ошибки на сервере, они логгируются и их легко можно найти. Плюс код сервера открыт для разработчиков и все легко ищется.

А теперь клиент. Представим, что вы сидите на JS с каким нибудь React/Vue/Angular, туда же запихаем babel, webpack и еще n-ое количество сторонних библиотек. И что-то из этого крашится у клиента.

Как это отлаживать? Допустим вы поймали ошибку с помощью try-catch (это же так делается?). Но у клиента нету source-map. У него ошибка ссылается на bandle.js, в котором итак без бутылки не разберешься, так он еще и нередко бывает обфусцирован.

Что делать то?

Comment: отлаживать ошибки нужно перед тем как сливать в продакшн

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Классический ответ индустрии на это - "тестировать", то есть покрывать всё самыми извращенными тестами, чтобы любая строчка кода была протестирована ПРЕЖДЕ чем она попадёт в бандл.

Это - результат боли, которую испытывают все разработчки фронтэнда. Потому что в отличие  от строго типизированных языков, где "вот он, код, вот сейчас мы его скомпилируем и потом будем запускать" - в JS на клиенте нет постоянного кода, а код каждую минтуту меняется - он подкачивает себя из сторонних ресурсов, само - модифицируется за счет добавления в себя функций и  изменяет поведение за счет модификации DOM.

На самом деле, конечно же, все не так сурово. Почти все популярные библиотеки, такие, как Angular или Vue - имеют девелоперскую, не обфусцированную версию.
И желательно на этапе выявления ошибок как то иначе собирать бандл, чтобы туда попадал только не обфусцированный код.

А еще есть сервисы для центррализованного сбора логов - что то типа Logstash или Sentry - в них надо отправлять ВСЁ что доступно в catch(). И потом над ним медитировать :-)

Ну, и кроме встроенного в браузер отладчика можно еще попробовать запускать код под средами разработки, такими, как WebStorm или Visual Studio (как ни удивительно, эта классическа среда имеет очень неплохой отладчик JS'а). Возможностей для отладки там больше, чем во встроенном отладчике.